# Unable to set up virtual host in xampp server

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am trying to set up a virtual host in my pc (windows 7). I am using xampp v3.2.1 which has apache 2.4.10, I get the following message from the xampp control panel while trying to start apache serviece.

```
9:55:07 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
9:55:07 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:55:07 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:55:07 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:55:07 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:55:07 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
9:55:07 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I am trying to set up the virtual host on `C:\www` directory. Here are the settings that I have in my `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts`

```
   <Directory C:/www>
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   </Directory>
    #
    # Use name-based virtual hosting.
    #
    ##NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/www/saseco"
        ServerName saseco.dev
        #</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
        ServerName localhost
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/www/saseco"
        ServerName saseco.dev
    </VirtualHost>
```

And this is what I have included in windows`...\etc\hosts` file

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
   #::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       saseco.dev
```

I have checked lots of tutorials and most of them were directing me to create virtual hosts the way I have done it. Is there any mistakes in my settings. I have also put off the firewall and removed skype just in case the problem is caused by them (as mentioned in some tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Is port 80 forwarded on your router? Check here:
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
If not, you will need to port forward port 80.

Comment: It says port 80 is open. Do I need port forwarding when creating virtual host in my local pc?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Binks. I uninstalled xampp and installed wamp, things are working fine in wamp